# What is the best way to run a scheduled batch with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

This is the first time I will work with Spring batch, and I got a task to do where I have to run a planned task every night at 00:00, which will truncate a table in the database, and re-fill it.

I don't know what is the best way to do this, I read a tutorial about Scheduling Tasks where I created a scheduled function and in this function I'll write the code which will execute my SQL scripts, as following :

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime(){
       //My code goes here
    }
}
```

But I don't know is this the best way to do it, since I found in some tutorials that they are working with `JobLauncher` and something called `job-report.xml`.

Any advices how to get this done ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 * * *")
```

Look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Don't forget to add @EnableScheduling to your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know about the `cron` attribute, what I meant by my question is that in some tutorials, you find people working with `Reader, Processor, Writer` then they create a configuration file to enable Spring batch and a JobLauncher Controller, and I don't know if this the right way to do it or using a `Scheduled` annotation is enough

Comment: I would just create a java application outside Spring and run it from the unix crontab.